# custom message in raise PermissionDenied not working in Django rest

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-permissions

I tried  **raise PermissionDenied("Anonymous user")** inside a custom permission function but the message I wrote is not showing in the api response. Instead, it is showing the default forbidden message that says **you dont have permission to perform this action**

My snippet is here:

```
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):
    """
        returns permission based on the request method and slug
    """

    def has_permission(self, request,view):
        slug = request.resolver_match.kwargs["slug"]
        if slug is not None and request.method == 'POST':
            if slug == "abc":
                user = request.user
                if user.is_staff:
                    return True
                if user.is_anonymous:
                    print("iam here")
                    raise PermissionDenied("Anonymous user")
            elif slug == "mnp":
                return True
        else:
            return True
```

**Here in the above code I reached to ("iam here") but anonymous user is not printing instead showing the default message.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change error message in message property:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions


class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Your message'

    def has_permission(self, request, view): 
        ... # return True or False
```

Docs in : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

After that, the `permission_denied(self, request, message=None, code=None)` function in your view would be called which `message` is the attribute that you have declared in your permission class.

You can use that, or even pass another message:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class YourView(...):
    permission_classes = [CustomerAccessPermission]

    def permission_denied(self, request, message=None, code=None):
        raise PermissionDenied(message)
```

Comment: I did  like you said and just return false, but cusotm message doent come in, instead the same default forbidden mesage

Comment: Sorry! I've updated my answer @Django-Rocks

Comment: I did this again, but still doenst work. I tried putting message in both inside permission_denied(self, request, message=None, code=None): and also in class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
  but still doesnt work

Comment: It' weird because it works for me! What version of DRF are you using? And be careful to import `PermissionDenied` from DRF not from django @Django-Rocks